# Acer Aspire V5-431 drivers for 12.10

Tags: drivers, acer, settings, animations

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my notebook ACER ASPIRE V5-431, but couldn't find drivers for this. Could anyone please tell me where could I find the drivers?

Also, I couldn't find the Appearance (Graphics Settings) in this version of Ubuntu.
Like it was there when I was using Ubuntu 9.

Nice animations were there while dragging windows or switching windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but I couldn't find any of these in this version.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the addition of the effects like what you've got in Ubuntu 9.XX, you should install CCSM, Compizconfig-settings-manager. Run below command on your Terminal.

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`